# Which privatekey format is this?

Tags: format, openssl, key, encryption

I've a private key made with OpenSSL and encrypted with RSA like this:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQILJ8rNTk54VICAggA
MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAiXuThuf12hMwSCBMhrm8H2j7yzLBOIvSWbLoyUmIn7e9zA
6PLDzj1dos+h+wAkPN0IgJlkdoBBXlnF7tzGdoctOYOKiu/p+HLzMnvHaDfNSFwz
5zx4yyZsKtf90gT6IVuJy7TMiLK3gk4gdZJc820OeRr1FjdRV3iVpTXbVfpwG/B3
IbV0PX3ZaHeR1m8vWI0/XQB7ZL7lLT+3MO66X/PAMTPA9joFMxuPFasIb2uXSqe/
CJNOyY4iW89uYHFiOe53e4ggUdT/rupoR4OSNKKEH5f1y+FIuH1xNvlmi14hJn+k
KOOi89vVIcvh4abCM+jhYwpPOGB8Sz2bAXsYocgZPvKtKakHlis7RcSsd5Usx9Nt
tgQ=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I've stored it into a `user.key` file.

Actually I'm implementing a CMS encrypt and decrypt project in objective-c. Now I'm trying to decrypt my encrypted container file using certificates, private key, and so on...
I'm a little bit confused which method from OpenSSL I should choose to load the aforementioned key into an `EVP_PKEY` object.

It suggests me the following formats:

- FORMAT_ASN1
- FORMAT_PEM
- FORMAT_PKCS12
- FORMAT_MSBLOB
- FORMAT_PVK

I know that it's not `PEM` and `PKCS12`. I would guess `ASN1` or `PVK` but I really don't know and I haven't found any further information on this in the OpenSSL docu.

Can anyone tell me please which format the aforementioned key has?

**EDIT:**
To specify my question a bit more: I have the aforementioned key loaded into a `BIO`. I can read this `BIO` with `BIO_read(keybio, ...)` successfully and it contains the key (in ascii). Now I want to get an `EVP_PKEY` from this `BIO`.
I've tried...

```
EVP_PKEY *key = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(keybio, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

... but this doesn't work. When I call this it asks me to enter the passphrase in the console and when I do this, the key is `NULL`. :-/

Comment: I found out that it works when the key is **not** password protected. Really strange... There are also some articles about this issue but without an answer. Maybe this is a bug in the OpenSSL library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is a [PKCS#8](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-8.asc) EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo wrapped in a PEM-container.

You can do something like this to get it into an `EVP_PKEY`-object:

```
// This must be called once: 
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

BIO* bio_err = BIO_new_fp (stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);

X509_SIG* p8 = PEM_read_bio_PKCS8(in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(p8==NULL){
  BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error decoding key\n");
  ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
  return;
}
PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO* p8inf = PKCS8_decrypt(p8, password, strlen(password));
if(p8inf==NULL){
  BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error decrypting key\n");
  ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
  return;
}
EVP_PKEY* pkey = EVP_PKCS82PKEY(p8inf);
if(pkey==NULL){
  BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error converting key\n");
  ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
  return;
}
```

Comment: @Chris: I added some error handling and the initialization call that you need to call once. If it still fails, let me know what the error is. It would also help if you could give me the password, so I could test the code myself.

Comment: What did you change? I had `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();` already at the begin of my method, so I removed your line but with your new code it works. Now I've the error that `CMS_decrypt(cms, key, cert, out, NULL, 0)` later in the code is `NULL` but that's a other problem. I'll do a little research and start a new post if I can't solve it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

That (extended) PEM format is used by OpenSSL for PKCS#8 encoded private keys.